# How to execute command in Python script?

Tags: python, subprocess

In my Python script I'm trying to execute next code:

```
import subprocess
subprocecss.call("xrdb -load ~/.XDefaults")
```

but it falls with error: "No such file or directory", although it works when I paste the same code to terminal. I also tryed os.system(...) with import os, I tried it with "xrdb -merge ~/.XDefaults", I tried to delete ~/ from command, I even tried to change "" to '', no way. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do what you want without using shell=True, I would also use check_call instead of call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `shell=True` or add your file with full path  :

```
subprocecss.call("xrdb -load ~/.XDefaults",shell=True)
```

from [python wiki](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) :

> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell
>
> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy).

Comment: I'm sorry for offtop, but maybe you can prompt me some messagebox where I can set foreground and background parameters

Comment: @banan-olivka .. its OK . if you want so there is better choices like `subpocecess.popen()`

Comment: I suppese, subprocess.popen(message='...', title='...', foreground='#000000', background='#ffffff'), but it raises error: '__init__() got unexpected keyword argument 'foreground' '

Comment: @banan-olivka you couldn't pass Arbitrary argument ...  you can pass your arguments in an iterable like list , pleas read the document https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Answer (score 1):

Note that since `subprocess.call` by default doesn't inherit your environment the value for ~ is not defined so you either need to pass the `shell=True` flag, *(potentially dangerous)*, or give the absolute path for `~/.XDefaults` by typing it in or using `os.path.expanduser('~/.XDefaults')` to get it, (as suggested by falstru).

Comment: What do you mean by `path.abspath`? If you mean `os.path.abspath`, it does not expand `~`.

Comment: On my system: `>>> os.path.abspath('~')
'/home/gadget/~'`

Comment: So, it's wrong function to use. Isn't it? (The function is depend on the current working directory. `~` itself is not expanded.)

Comment: You may want to use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser): `os.path.expanduser('~/.XDefaults')`

Comment: Better will add to answer.